# No sound emitted from discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm currently using Discord.js v12 (Ubuntu 20.04, Node.js v14.0.0), and I've had no luck playing any sound.

Sample code (voice_connection designates a VoiceConnection instance as defined in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection)):

```js
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core-discord");
...
const data = await ytdl(/* some youtube url */, { filter: "audioonly" });
const dispatcher = voice_connection.play(data);
```

I've installed `ffmpeg@0.0.4`, `opusscript@0.0.7`, `@discordjs/opus@0.3.2` and `ffmpeg-static@4.0.1`.

Furthermore, when listening to the dispatcher's `debug` event, I receive the following error after around 10 seconds of running the code:

```
Error: ffmpeg stream: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:92:16) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

**The end goal is:** fixing the issue which is, the bot not playing any sound, local file or remote URL.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const channel = message.member.voice.channel;
    channel.join().then(connection => {
        const dispatcher = connection.play(path.join(__dirname + 'path.mp3'));
        dispatcher.on('speaking', speaking => {
            if(!speaking) channel.leave();
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

you can try and play the audio file this way, I already tested it and it works for me!